# How to restore database programatically from backup with multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, smo

I have no problem with restoring database programatically (in C# using SMO) from backup containing one file. But when the backup contains multiple files (full and differential backups) I get the following error

> The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are
>   ready to rollforward

So what should I do to restore database with the latest data?

Comment: How are the files laballed? If all your files were mydb.bak then no it wont know which order to do them. as only 1 can exist any point in time..

Comment: In a backup file set there are multiple files named 'mydb-differential database backup', 'mydb-full database backup' and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the `NoRecovery` Option so that it will allow you to restore the rest of the files.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.norecovery.aspx) for reference.